# Concepts of archiving all the user accounts in Ubuntu

Tags: server, tar, archive

I have given a task to archive all the user accounts for a given batch and delete the user accounts of the students for that batch. Such archiving could be useful for setting up the system for the next batch after the current batch of students left.

Basically for what I have done:

1. I have created multiple user accounts on Ubuntu.
2. For each user accounts, I created daily backup for the accounts home dir using the code as shown:

   `0 0 * * * sudo tar -cpzf /backupfolder/user1_backup-$(date +\%Y--\%m-\%d).tar.gz /home/students/user1`

For my current tasks, may I know how should I archive all the user accounts and delete them? I still barely understand the concepts behind of doing so and why it is useful for setting up system for the next batch?

Thank you for your guides!